# MVC4 adding to a list contained inside model without redirecting from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to work out how to add items to a list contained inside my MVC pages model without reloading the page.

I have a form as shown in the picture below. The page runs off an "Applicant" model which has a list of "Contact".

When doing an "Application", the user needs to be able to add multiple "Contacts". When the "plus" sign is clicked, it will add a new "Contact" item to the list.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUvb7.png

I've tried multiple ways (Actionlinks etc) but every way seems to redirect the page.

If anyone can help shed some light on this it'd be greatly appreciated

This is a cut down example of my model

```
public class ApplicantMessage : PersonMessage
{
    //... Other properties here
    public virtual ICollection<ContactMessage> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

This is the div region which defines the "Contact" details (Note, I didn't know whether or how to use @Html.TextBoxFor(..) here)

```
<!-- Other Contacts -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
        <label class="label">Other Contacts</label>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <input type="text" class="new-contact-details"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span4">
        @Html.DropDownList("contactMethodDropdown", default(ContactMethod).ValueList(), new{@class="dropdown-slim"})
        <input type="text" class="new-contact-contact-details"/>
        <a rel="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Add a contact" class="icon-plus"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```
public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NewApplication()
    {
        var message = new ApplicantMessage();
        return View(message);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewApplication(ApplicantMessage message)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //add to DB
        }
        return View(message);
    }

}
```

Also, it should be worth noting that the contacts need displaying on the right hand side of the page. I assume that will be done using some sort of partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use indexes for your contacts when posting your `ApplicantMessage` model to your controller.

Basically, your HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span4">
        @Html.DropDownList("Contacts[0].ContactMethod", default(ContactMethod).ValueList(), new{@class="dropdown-slim"})
        <input type="text" name="Contacts[0].Name" class="new-contact-contact-details"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        @Html.DropDownList("Contacts[1].ContactMethod", default(ContactMethod).ValueList(), new{@class="dropdown-slim"})
        <input type="text" name="Contacts[1].Name" class="new-contact-contact-details"/>
        <a rel="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Add a contact" class="icon-plus"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the indexers? Your modelbinder will automatically create an array based on these. When adding extra contacts through javascript, you'll also need to make sure your indexes increment accordingly.

For more information, you should read this (old, but still very relevant) [post by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: Hi chap, thanks for this. I did try looking for old articles but couldn't find any. This is mostly what I need (though, when a contact is added, I want to clear the values in the box, not add more). However I should be able to use the basics from this to get my solution.

Comment: And you still need ajax in order to retrieve that html bit :)